# Matlab: Speed up loop applied to each of 820,000 elements

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a set of rainfall data, with a value every 15 minutes over many years, giving 820,000 rows.
The aim (eventually) of my code is to create columns which categorise the data which can then be used to extract relevant chunks of data for further analysis.

I am a Matlab novice and would appreciate some help!

The first steps I have got working sufficiently fast.  However, some steps are very slow.

I have tried pre-allocating arrays, and using the lowest intX (8 or 16 depending on situation) possible, but other steps are so slow they don't complete.

The slow ones are for loops, but I don't know if they can be vectorised/split into chunks/anything else to speed them up.

I have a variable "rain" which contains a value for every time step/row.
I have created a variable called "state" of 0 if no rain, and 1 if there is rain.
Also a variable called "begin" which has 1 if it is the first row of a storm, and 0 if not.

The first slow loop is to create a "spell" variable - to give each rain storm a number.

```
% Generate blank column for spell of size (rain) - preallocate
    spell = zeros(size(st),1,'int16');

% Start row for analysis
    x=1;

% Populate "spell" variable with a storm number in each row of rain, for the storm number it belongs to (storm number calculated by adding up the number of "begin" values up to that point

    for i=1:size(state)
         if(state(x)==1)
             spell(x) =  sum(begin(1:x));
         end
       x=x+1;
    end
```

The next stage is about length of each storm.  The first steps are fast enough.

```
 % List of storm numbers

     spellnum = unique(spell);

 % Length of each spell
     spelllength = histc(spell,spellnum);
```

The last step below (the for loop) is too slow and just crashes.

```
 % Generate blank column for length

      length = zeros(size(state),1,'int16');

 % Starting row

      x = 1;

 % For loop to output the total length of the storm for each row of rain within that storm

     for i=1:size(state)

          for j=1:size(state)
                 position = find(spell==x);

                      for k=1:size(state)
                          length(position) = spelllength(x+1);
                      end
          end

       x=x+1;

      end
```

Is it possible to make this more efficient?

Apologies if examples already exist - I'm not sure what the process would be called!
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have memory constraints, or you have enough memory for your run?

Comment: I have just upgraded to a 64-bit computer last week, so I have as much memory as I'm going to get!
I was getting "out of memory" errors on my previous computer, but not yet on this one.

Comment: Code Catastrophe with `i` as the same iterator for three nested loops.

Comment: Ok, that's useful to know.  I have replaced the second and third nest iterators with `j` and `k`, but it is still crashing...

Comment: If before tonight nobody answers it I'll do tonight. What are the dimensions of your matrices and vectors?

Comment: Thank you!  Each variable is a single column with 819891 rows...! (Except `spelllength` and `spellnum` which are one column with 33284 rows - i.e. there are 33284 storms in my dataset.)

Comment: i think you should replace size with length in your code
size gives you all the dimensions while length just gives the long one which i assume is what you need

Comment: can you give us some data to check if it's running as required

Comment: Just got back from my other job and pleased to see so many answers!  Just trying them out and trying to understand what they do.

Example data: `rain = [0;0;1;1;0;0;0;3;3;1;0;0;0;7;0];`
             `state = [0;0;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0];`
             `begin = [0;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0];`

Comment: Ah, I have never met the "length" function before - yes, "length" would be more sensible than "size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of code I have ended up using is a mixture from @CST_Link and @Sifu.  Thank you very much for your help!  I don't think Stackoverflow lets me accept two answers, so for clarity by putting it all together, here is the code which everyone's helped me create!

The only slow part is the for loop in block three, but this still runs in a few minutes, which is good enough for me, and infinitely better than my attempt.

First block:

```
%% Spell
%spell is cumulative sum of begin

spell = cumsum(begin);

%% start row
x=1;

%% Replace all rows of spell with no rain with 0
spell(state==0)=0
```

Second block (unchanged except better variable names):

```
%%  Spell number = all values of spell

spell_num = unique(spell);

%% Spell length = how many of each value of spell
spell_length = histc(spell,spell_num);
```

Third block:

```
%% Generate blank column for spell of size (state)
 spell_length2 = zeros(length(state),1);

%%
for x=1:length(state)
    position = find(spell==x);
    spell_length2(position) = spell_length(x+1);
end
```

Comment: In order to effective linearisation, you should let the loops go for a little bit... For example, the `for` loop that replaces all rows of spell with no rain with 0: you should do exactly that, i.e. `spell(state==0)=0`. But note that this will insert a new value among your uniques, and that value is 0 itself.

Comment: In your third block, you don't have to assign `x=1;`. The for loop explicitely starts at 1 ([See official documentation on For Loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html)). In your first block, do similar to my third block (remove `x=1;` `x=x+1` and replace `for i=1:length(state)` with `for x=1:length(state)`. Don't forget that you can always get very clear documentation on anything using the command `>doc {Command}`. Ex `>doc for` will give really good documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: CST-Link That is much neater - I didn't realise it was possible.  I will amend the code accordingly.
Sifu Thank you - I didn't realise you could call up the documentation so easily.  I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Mem. allocation/reallocation tips:

1. try to create the results directly from expression (eventually trimming another, more general result);
2. if 1. is not possible, try to pre-allocate whenever possible (when you have an upper limit for the result);
3. if 2. is not possible try to grow cell-arrays rather than massive matrices (because a matrix requires a contiguous memory area)

Type-choice tips:

1. try to use always `double` in intermediate results, because is the basic numeric data type in MATLAB; avoiding conversions back and forth;
2. use other types for intermediate results only if there's a memory constraint that can be alleviated by using a smaller-size type.

Linearisation tips:

1. fastest linearisation uses matrix-wise or element-wise basic algebraic operations combined with logical indexing.
2. loops are not that bad starting with MATLAB R2008;
3. the worst-performing element-wise processing functions are `arrayfun`, `cellfun` and `structfun` with anonymous functions, because anon functions evaluate the slowest;
4. try not to calculate the same things twice, even if this gives you better linearisation.

First block:

```
% Just calculate the entire cumulative sum over begin, then
% trim the result. Check if the cumsum doesn't overflow.
spell           = cumsum(begin);
spell(state==0) = 0;
```

Second block:

```
% The same, not sure how could you speed this up; changed
% the name of variables to my taste, though.
spell_num    = unique(spell);
spell_length = histc(spell,spell_num);
```

Third block:

```
% Fix the following issues: 
%   - the most-inner "for" does not make sense because it rewrites
%     several times the same thing;
%   - the same looping variable "i" is re-used in three nested loops,
%   - thename of the standard function "length" is obscured by declaring
%     a variable named "length".
for x = 1:numel(spell_num)
        storm_selector = (spell==spell_num(x));
        storm_length(storm_selector) = spell_length(x+1);
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget that comments in MatLab are `%` not `'`.

Comment: Thank you!  First block: I would like to keep the non-rain rows as zeros, so have taken `spell=cumsum(begin)`, but then had to add `for i=1:size(state)
 if(state(x)==0)
   spell(x) =  0;
    end
 x=x+1;
end` to put the zeros back... Seems to work and is still faster than what I had before.  
Second block, I see the logic of your naming!  
Third block, glad to hear I don't need all the nested loops - todays loops are the first I have ever written so lots to learn.  However, I am not having success with the third block code.  Errors galore incl. "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Comment: I guess it would work to add Sifu's code for the third block onto your code for the first and second?

Comment: @Sifu Thanks for the note about comments, I just got puzzled answering MATLAB and VBA related questions.

Comment: @user1913275 As you wish, is you who in the end decides what will work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

for the first part if i am following what you are doing
i created some data matching your description for testing.
please tell me if i missed something

```
state=[ 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0];
begin=[ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]; 
spell = zeros(length(state),1,'int16');
%Start row for analysis
    x=1;

% Populate "spell" variable with a storm number in each row of rain, for the storm number it belongs to (storm number calculated by adding up the number of "begin" values up to that point

    for i=1:length(state)
         if(state(x)==1)
             spell(x) =  sum(begin(1:x));
         end
       x=x+1;
    end
% can be accomplished by simply using cumsum ( no need for extra variables if you are short in memory)


   spell2=cumsum(begin);
    spell3=spell2.*(state==1);
```

and the output for both spell and spell3 as shown

```
[spell.'; spell3]

 0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      0      2      0      0      2      0      3      3    3      3      0
 0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      0      2      0      0      2      0      3      3      3      3      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do that instead?

```
% For loop to output the total length of the storm for each row of rain within that storm

for x=1:size(state)
    position = find(spell==x);
    length(position) = spelllength(x+1);
end
```

I replaced the `i` iterator for `x`, that removes 2 lines and some computation.
I then proceeded to removed the two nested loops as they were litteraly useless (each loop would output the same thing)
That's already a good start..

Comment: This certainly works faster, and as long as I remember to preallocate with zeros first, gives me what I want.
However, I get the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."
I guess this is because of the (x+1), and therefore I don't need to worry... I hope this is the case!

Comment: @user1913275 Yes it could be cause by that.. I suggest that you read CST-Link answer, as it covers many more errors that could be detrimental in the later phases of your program.